# Two step entity reference selection

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a two step entity reference selection in Drupal 9.

The structure so far:

Content Type: **Company**

--> Entity reference: Jobs (multiple)

Content Type: **Job**

--> Entity reference: Qualification (multiple)

Content Type: **Qualification**

I created an import for the company profiles and there is a entity reference for multiple jobs. This is already working.

In a second step there should be a **selection of qualifications** within the company profile. But this selection should be **limited** to the qualifications defined by the relation between job and qualification.

I was looking for a structure like this:

[image: form structure]

I already tested the [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) and [Conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) modules. But the problem is these solutions base on a single selection in the first step. I have a multiple selection in the first step (jobs).